# Need a good handbook of ubuntu as because i am a beginer in this subject

Tags: networking

Can anyone give me good hand book links of ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great guide to get started.  Truly the best way is to dig in and use Google when you get stuck.  Terminal is your friend and not your enemy (remember that).

http://ubuntu-manual.org/

I think this is a great way to introduce yourself to Ubuntu.  Another great way to understand Ubuntu specifically is to understand that Ubuntu is a distribution of Linux built on Debian Linux.  Linux comes in many 'flavors' and you just need to find what works for you.  I am always happy to see new Linux users eager to learn. My advice is to jump in and start playing around.  It is not as scary as it seems. Open-source and free is the way to be :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new book that just came out and covers 16.04. You can buy a physical copy of it in the link below.

[Ubuntu Unleashed](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0134268113)

Here is another handbook you can read online for free.

[Ubuntu Official Book 7th Edition](http://www.svecc.com/SLUG/slug_pdf/The%20Official%20Ubuntu%20Book,%207th%20Edition.pdf)